# My React component fetch or axios is not posting the values to Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a component written as below

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../assets/js/CommonFunctions.js'
import * as clientConfiguration from '../assets/clientConfiguration.json'

class AccessData extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
};

state = {
    files: [],
    communities: [],
    selectedCommunity: { display: "Select a Community...", value: "" },
    communityValidationError: "",
    downloadButtonVisibile: false
};

handleDownload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let communityName = this.state['selectedCommunity'];
    let checkedFiles = this.state.files.filter(i => i.checked);
    console.log(checkedFiles);
    //axios({
    //    method: 'post',
    //    url: clientConfiguration['filesApi.local'],
    //    body: {
    //        communityname: communityName,
    //        files: files
    //    }
    //});

    fetch(clientConfiguration['filesApi.local'], {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers(),
        body: {
            communityname: communityName,
            files: checkedFiles
        }
    }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log(clientConfiguration)


    fetch(clientConfiguration['communitiesApi.local'])
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            let communitiesFromApi = data.map(community => { return { value: community, display: community } })
            this.setState({ communities: [{ value: '', display: 'Select a Community...' }].concat(communitiesFromApi) });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};

handleDDLCommunityChange = event => {
    this.setState(
        {
            selectedCommunity: event.target.value
        });

    if (event.target.value == "") {
        this.setState(
            {
                files: null
            });
    }
    else {
        fetch(clientConfiguration['filesApi.local'] + '/' + event.target.value)
            .then((response) => { return response.json(); })
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    files: response.map(file => {
                        return {
                            fileName: file,
                            checked: false
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                debugger;
            });
    }

};

handleFileSelection = event => {
    const files = [...this.state.files];
    let selectedFile = event.target.value;
    selectedFile = files.find(file => file.fileName === selectedFile);
    selectedFile.checked = event.target.checked;
    this.setState({
        files
    });
};

renderDownloadButton() {
    if (this.state.files && this.state.files.filter(i => i.checked).length) {
        return (
            <button id="download" styles="display: none;" onClick={this.handleDownload} >
                Download
    </button>
        );
    }
};

render() { 
    const { files } = this.state;
    return (
        <main>
            <div className="aqview-header">
                <div className="container about">
                    <div className="header-tab">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div className="text-wrap">
                                    <h1>Access Data</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="container">
                <div className="aqview-section">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <p>
                                The files available for download below are preliminary data files from AB 617 monitoring. Please note that we are currently working with data providers to make data available for each listed community below, so please check back if you do not see data for your community.
                                Available data are grouped into monthly files, with new data added weekly. Please select the AB 617 community you are interested in to begin downloading files.
                    </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="download_tool">
                        <form id="download_form" method="post" >
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-12">
                                    <div className="header-box">
                                        <h2>Data Download Tool</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <select id="communityName" title="Select a Community" name="communityName" onChange={this.handleDDLCommunityChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.selectedCommunity.display}>
                                        {this.state.communities.map((community) => <option key={community.value} value={community.value}>{community.display}</option>)}
                                    </select>
                                    <div id="file_list_box">
                                        <p><strong>Data Files</strong></p>
                                        <ul id="file_listing">
                                            {files && files.map((file, i) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <li key={i}>
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input
                                                                type="checkbox"
                                                                name="file"
                                                                value={file.fileName}
                                                                onChange={this.handleFileSelection}
                                                            />
                                                            {file.fileName}
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                                );
                                            })}
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    {this.renderDownloadButton()}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="aqview-section">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <p>
                                    Disclaimer: This download tool only provides preliminary data files that have not been verified
                                    or extensively quality assured. These files should not be used for any official purposes.
                    </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="aqview-section">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <p>
                                    Provide feedback at <a href="mailto:aqview@arb.ca.gov">AQview@arb.ca.gov</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
}
export default connect()(AccessData);
```

I am not understanding when I check the Api its receiving only empty string for communityName and empty array for the files collection, I am pasting the Api code also here:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public FileContentResult Post([FromForm] string communityName, [FromForm] string[] files)
    {
        //communityName = "Community-1";
        string rootPath = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ROOT_PATH");
        string communityPath = rootPath + "\\" + communityName;

        byte[] theZipFile = null;

        using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (string attachment in files)
                {
                    var zipEntry = zip.CreateEntry(attachment);

                    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(communityPath + "\\" + attachment, FileMode.Open))
                    using (Stream entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            theZipFile = zipStream.ToArray();
        }

        return File(theZipFile, "application/zip", communityName + ".zip");
    }
```

And another problem I am facing is, this post method returns a zip file, usually it should automatically download when the button is clicked, and the previous app was in jQuery and it was downloading the zip file without different code I don't know for some reason even if I hard coded communityName in the api so that to test if the download is working - it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous and also invokes componentDidUpdate life cycle and re-renders. Thus your API call might not go to the subsequent lines.

Move your setState  calls after your API call to debug.

Comment: In which component am I doing it buddy? Can you please give me little bit more details please - Thank you.

Comment: And console.log(checkedFiles); I put just before the api call, gives me results though, just api is not receiving the parameters, I don't know what's happening.